# Testing an MVP Android Application with Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit, mvp

I'm trying to do some unit test on a basic Android app. it just do a login to some WS using retrofit my app has a MVP pattern.

What I'm doing?

call to presenter layer this will call to interactor and here I will call to my service

```
    @Override
    public void doLogin(String user, String pwd, final LoginListener loginListener) {

        try {
            final LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
            request.setEmpleado(user);
            request.setPwd(pwd);

            Callback<LoginResponse> callback = new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                    if(response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        if("00".equals(response.body().getCodigo())) {
                            loginListener.authOK();
                        } else {
                            loginListener.showError();
                        }
                    } else {
                        loginListener.showError();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
"+t.getMessage()+" "+t.getCause());
                    if(t instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                        loginListener.showError();
                    } else {
                        loginListener.showError();
                    }
                }
            };

            WSLogin wsLogin = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getRetrofit().create(WSLogin.class);
            wsLogin.autenticar(request).enqueue(callback);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            loginListener.showError();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My service it's called but i never get into callback

Test

```
package com.arleckk.loginmvpci.login;


import com.arleckk.loginmvpci.login.presenter.LoginListener;
import com.arleckk.loginmvpci.login.presenter.LoginPresenter;
import com.arleckk.loginmvpci.login.presenter.LoginPresenterImpl;
import com.arleckk.loginmvpci.login.view.LoginView;
import com.arleckk.loginmvpci.model.LoginResponse;
import com.arleckk.loginmvpci.network.WSLogin;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.IOException;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
public class LoginTest {

    @Mock private LoginView loginView;
    @Mock private LoginPresenter loginPresenter;
    @Mock private LoginListener loginListener;
    @Mock private Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall;
    Response<LoginResponse> loginResponseResponse;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        loginPresenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(loginView);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOK() throws IOException {
        loginPresenter.doLogin("TEST", "TEST1234");
    }


}
```

Another question is: do am I really doing unit test? I mean unit test only test a "Unit" of the code.

I'm expecting a LoginResponse object and then compare it and if it is equals to "00" it's sucessful

Comment: The answer is spot on: you are starting this from the wrong end. Read a good book or tutorial about JUnit and unit testing, like this one: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html and then start with really small units to tests. Of course, using JUnit to automate large integration tests is possible and sometimes useful, too. But you should understand that what you are doing is really not a "unit" test.

Comment: is it more like "integration testing"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not.  For a few reasons.  First off, you don't have a test here.  You don't have a single assertion.  No matter what happens your code will say pass.  So it isn't a test.  A test would be to say call doLogin with a working login, and ensure that loginListener.authOK() is called.  Then another test that uses a bad password, and checks that showError is called.  Without that all you have is a waste of time.

Second-  this is horribly scoped for a unit test.  For a unit test, you should be checking that the smallest unit of code works.  Here, you're checking that your entire networking stack, and your server, all work.  That's way too much.  And a unit test should never depend on an outside server working, that will just lead to a flaky test-  something like that should be in an integration suite.

Your code right now isn't optimized for testing.  If it was-  you wouldn't be creating the retrofit client via a singleton in the code.  You'd pass it into doLogin.  That way you could pass in a mock in a test that could return a fake response, and then test whether your code can correctly identify the a fake success and failure response correctly, removing the server dependency yet testing all of the functionality.

Comment: thanks I still have a lot to learn. I will study again how to do a proper Unit Test and Integration Test.